# Android monkey runner: Touch with MOVE

Tags: android, touch, drag, move, monkeyrunner

I am trying to use monkeyrunner to simulate complex touch events.
A swipe from a to b with...

```
device.drag((300,500),(300,650),0.5,50)
```

works great but a complex movement from a to b to c doesn't work trying with that

```
device.touch(100,500, 'DOWN')
device.touch(300,500, 'MOVE')
device.touch(300,400, 'MOVE')
device.touch(300,400, 'UP')
```

Was seaching for a solution and found this..
https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/50991/

Is this already implemenet in the offical android sdk?
or did i have to compile it or something else and how it works?

I dont really know but i think this side is the official monkeyrunner source..
[MonkeyDevice.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/swt/+/d9880c7c4d4c12d94d2059453361f1c3691a901d/monkeyrunner/src/main/java/com/android/monkeyrunner/MonkeyDevice.java) and this one have the "MOVE" type on line 70.
But the TouchAction.java on same side at line 28 have no "MOVE" implemented.
So maybe that's the reason why it's not working.

Can somebody tell me how i get complex touch movement on android phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it merged to official SDK tools now.
You can use it.
Just care about delay between MOVE and MOVE.

Here is a [link](https://gist.github.com/sjp38/6202539) to sample code for you.
I have tested the code on my Galaxy Nexus.