# Genymotion scripting

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

Is it possible to create some kind of scripting with Genymotion?

I know there is shell commands, but I also need to simulate user touch (using adb input).

The idea is to create some simple test for my app, where the script will execute certain shell commands and adb as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As Genymotion VMs are considered as a physical device by ADB, you can use [MonkeyRunner](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html).

This tool, provided by Google allows you to send touches events among other things.

You can script, using Python many inputs. Look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/sjp38/6202539), coming from [this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18161416/android-monkey-runner-touch-with-move) post, it gives good example for a complete gesture.